# Add a new column to a dataframe which is the result of a groupby count

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the total number of books that an author wrote and put it in a column called book number with my dataframe that has 15 other columns.

I checked online and people use groupby with count(), however it doesn't create the column that I want, it only gives a column of numbers without a name and I can't put it together with the original dataframe.

```py
author_count_df = (df_author["Name"]).groupby(df_author["Name"]).count()

print(author_count_df)
```

Result:

```
Name
A  D                3
A  Gill             4
A  GOO              3
ALL  SHOT          10
AMIT  PATEL         5
                   ..
vishal  raina       7
walt  walter        6
waqas  alhafidh     3
yogesh  koshal      8
zainab  m.jawad     9
Name: Name, Length: 696, dtype: int64
```

Expected: A dataframe with

```
Name          other 14 columns from author_df   Book Number
A  D                    ...                         3
A  Gill                 ...                         4
A  GOO                  ...                         3
ALL  SHOT               ...                         10
AMIT  PATEL             ...                         5
                        ...                         ..
vishal  raina           ...                         7
walt  walter            ...                         6
waqas  alhafidh         ...                         3
yogesh  koshal          ...                         8
zainab  m.jawad         ...                         9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use transform with the groupby and assign it back:

```
df_author['Book Number']=df_author.groupby("Name")['Name'].transform('count')
```

For a new df, use:

```
author_count_df = df_author.assign(BookNum=df_author.groupby("Name")['Name']
                                                        .transform('count'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
author_count_df = (df_author["Name"]).groupby(df_author["Name"]).count().reset_index()
```

This basically tells the pandas groupby to reset back to the original index

Answer (score 0):

You have done the good Job except you need to check how to populate or assign the values back into a new column which you have got, Which you can achieve with **[`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)** method which does the Job quite elegantly.

Straight from the Docs:

> 1. Assign new columns to a DataFrame.
> 2. Returns a new object with all original columns in addition to new ones. Existing columns that are re-assigned will be overwritten.